# Better method for loading a list of items to be parsed into two, and calling the matching item by index?

Tags: c#, list, combobox

I have a .txt file with a list of items (u.s. state and capitals) going down such as Arizona:Phoenix Arkansas:Little Rock California:Sacramento. I'm going to be importing that list, but only want to display the States in a Combobox. After that, if comboBox1.Items[0] is selected, I want it to get the corresponding item that was initially parsed along with it after the : delimiter. My initial solution was to create a class to hold both values, and hold them in a List and compare the index from the Combobox to that of the List to get the matching value. I feel like this might be overkill and I am over thinking it for something as simple as a combobox where the data won't be subjected to any complex manipulations. Would there be a simpler method/datatype to use to do this? I just want to get the corresponding value after the : delimiter from the Combobox index that was parsed when it was first loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all build your classes of `State` & `Capital` like this:

```
    public class State
    {
        public string stateName { get; set; }
        public Capital capital { get; set; }
    }
    public class Capital
    {
        public string capitalName { get; set; }
    }
```

Read the text file, generate a list and populate the `ComboBox` like this:

```
    List<State> list = new List<State>();
    var file = File.ReadAllLines(FilePath).ToList();
    foreach (var item in file)
    list.Add(new State()
    {
       stateName = item.Split(':')[0],
       capital = new Capital() { capitalName = item.Split(':')[1] }
     });
    StatesCB.DataSource = list.Select(x => x.stateName).ToList();
```

And within your `ComboBoxIndexChange` eventHandler, get the Capital based on the State.

```
    private void Sates_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        capital.Text = list.Where(x => x.stateName == StatesCB.SelectedValue)
                    .Select(x => x.capital.capitalName).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

It works and address your problem perfetcly.

Comment: This is essentially what I had in mind. I guess I'm just going to go ahead and go with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

I assume your text file contains the following lines:

```
Arizona:Phoenix
Arkansas:Little
Rock California:Sacramento
```

On your code:

```
 List<string> lstResult = new List<string>();
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Stack\file.txt"))
        {

            string line = string.Empty;
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                //Here I am getting the second part of splitted string which is your requirement
                lstResult.Add(line.Split(':').Select(x=>x).Skip(1).SingleOrDefault().ToString());    
            }
        }

        comboBox1.DataSource = lstResult;
```

This will produce:

[image]

Comment: I already know how to split and input it into the combobox. I am just looking to see if there's a simpler way to save both values and be able to call the corresponding value of the current Combobox index, instead of splitting it every time I need it from the original lstResult buffer index.